# Where is defined path to database.yml in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Where is defined path to `database.yml` in rails?

I am about worked project. In development it equal to `config` in same folder where is `app` folder. In production deployed by capistrano it equal `~/sites/shared/config`.

Is it convention? Where it is documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hardcoded to be `<app-root>/config/database.yml`. In production environment where you store it in a shared folder, you must create a symlink that points to that shared file.

```
 <app-root>/config/database.yml -> ~/sites/shared/config/database.yml
```

Or you could symlink the whole config directory, if you wanted.

Comment: Or use `ENV["DATABASE_URL"]` instead of monkeying around with file based configuration.